# Change CRS to long/lat in Terra

Tags: r, reference, coordinates, terra

I'm working with rasterdata using `Terra` in `R`, but I'm not familiar with it. What I try to do is to change the CRS to long/lat.
I was able to load the `.tif` file as `SpatRaster` class.

I can extract the coordinate information as

```
r <- rast("file.tif")
```

```
> r
class       : SpatRaster
dimensions  : 700, 700, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : 3e+05, 1e+06, 3e+05, 1e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_0=50.797815 +lon_0=4.35921583333333 +lat_1=49.8333333333333 +lat_2=51.1666666666667 +x_0=649328 +y_0=665262 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
source      : 20200101000000.radclim.accum1h.tif
name        : 20200101000000.radclim.accum1h
```

```
> dataframe_r <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
> head(dataframe_r)
       x      y 2020010104
1 300500 999500          0
2 301500 999500          0
3 302500 999500          0
4 303500 999500          0
5 304500 999500          0
6 305500 999500          0
```

I try to get coordinates in lon/lat format. Can someone help me with it?

I tried

```
> proj <- project(r,  "+proj=longlat")
```

but, then I'm not using the coord. ref. from the SpatRaster...

Comment: What are you doing next in your analysis that suggests transforming to 'long/lat' is useful?

Comment: I need to compare precipitation accumulation to the rain gauges, for which only long/lat coordinates are available.

Comment: Perhaps, `terra::vect(your_rain_guage_data`, then `project(your_rain_guage_data, "+proj=lcc +lat_0=50.797815 +lon_0=4.35921583333333 +lat_1=49.8333333333333 +lat_2=51.1666666666667 +x_0=649328 +y_0=665262 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")`, here just copy pasting the proj string from the raster., Then plot together to see if it makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean with "lat" "long"? It is way too generic (and not unique), so there may not be conversion from your initial coordinates. Possible `EPSG:4326` aka WGS84 aka lat and long as defined by GPS may be a better choice. "latlong" is just to be used when you do not need conversions and you do not know exactly where the origin is set.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want the lon/lat coordinates of the raster cells of a raster with a different crs. In that case, you could do

```
pts <- as.points(r, na.rm=FALSE) 
pts <- project(pts, "+proj=longlat")
lonlatpts <- crds(pts)
```

But that approach does not seem very helpful given what you say in the comments. You could transform your points instead.

```
v <- vect(stations, crs="+proj=longlat")
pv <- project(v, r)
crdpv <- crds(pv)
```

And even that is probably not what you *really, really* want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That's indeed what I needed! The `as.points()` take away the raster and only work with a cloud of points, not specific on a raster, which also makes the projection correct now. Thank you!